# Why is -pthread necessary for usage of std::thread in GCC and Clang?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, gcc, clang

Why does specifying `-std=c++11` when compiling a program that directly or indirectly uses `std::thread` not imply `-pthread`? It seems strange that the implementation detail of `std::thread` using pthreads under the hood is exposed to the programmer; if it's a matter of giving the user a choice of posix-compatible threading libraries, why not just default to pthreads and have some `--threading-model=<your_favorite_posix_threads_library>` argument to override it?

Comment: Would it help you if you think of "GCC for C++" as "`g++ -pthread -std=c++11`" and don't worry about the lexical noise in the definition?

Comment: @KerrekSB It makes it a pain when using CMake and actually trying to be cross-platform without resorting to explicit modification of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS (Microsoft's compiler does complain about the unknown flags but ignores them) or putting platform/`find_library` conditionals, especially if the behavior _does_ end up changing eventually. One mailing list I found suggested using `find_package(Threads)`, but that doesn't seem to work with GCC or Clang. I'm not looking for a solution as I already know what to do, I'm just trying to find out why they behave that way. Is it just backwards-compat?

Comment: I do not think there is a reason. Noone cared too much to change the behaviour, which was inherited from pre-C++11 compiler.

Comment: (I actually just got `find_package(Threads)` working right, invalidating that part of my previous comment, but whatever.)

Comment: On some platforms, libc comes with 2 versions of many functions, one that is fast but not thread-safe, and a slower one that is thread-safe. Linking with libpthread switches it from using one version to the other. So `-pthread` makes single-threaded programs slower and some people don't want it by default.

Comment: @MarcGlisse That seems like a failure in design. What happens if a programmer wants to use the thread-unsafe functions when they know only one of their threads will use them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-pthread` option is not universally required to use `std::thread` - it's an implementation quirk of whatever platform you're building on.

Compiling:

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::thread t{[]()
        {
            std::cout << "Hello World\n";
        }};
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

with

```
clang -std=c++11 ThreadTest.cpp -lc++
```

On MacOSX, builds and runs, and if we do:

```
otool -L a.out 
a.out:
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1225.0.0)
```

We can see that we've needed to link nothing extra to make this work - nor has it happened behind the scenes.  It seems to be very much a platform implementation detail that pthreads is a separate library.

Having a choice of threading libraries with the pthread interface is legacy baggage on *NIX systems, many of which started off without thread support, then went through a phase of user-space threads before having full kernel support.   I guess it's still there because nobody likes making breaking changes.

Comment: "I guess it's still there because nobody likes making breaking changes" but since you have to change code anyhow to make use of std::thread I don't see how defining it in such a way to assume lpthread if nothing else is specified would break anything?

Comment: The change I was referring to was the need to include libpthread in any program that uses threading on some platforms.  C++11 compliant tools and libraries are very largely backward compatible to C++03 code-bases.

One really has to wonder why pthreads is still factored out into a separate library.

Comment: Well that's interesting. Out of curiosity, what C++ library is used on OSX if you build with Clang but don't specify `-lc++`?

Comment: Fails to link. unless I use `clang++` as the compiler driver.  Clang++ links with `/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib` and `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib`.