# Which C++ standard library headers invoke a requirement for the -pthread option with GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, pthreads, libstdc++

If you use C++ threads with the GCC compiler (or perhaps more accurately, with the libstdc++ C++ standard library which ships with GCC) on Linux, you [may need to include the `-pthread` option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33697072/3022952) in your build process to get things to compile and link properly.

What I'm curious about is which library headers invoke that requirement? `#include <thread>` is an obvious one, but are there other standard library headers which implicitly have a pthread dependency for libstdc++?

Comment: probably <future>

Comment: Assume **ALL**.  The standard doesn't have any restrictions on standard headers including other headers so `<iostream>` could have `<thread>` included.

Comment: If your implementation uses `pthread` or not for threading is an implementation detail. If you get a linker error add the library. When I include standard threading headers `<thread>` I don't need to specifically link against `-lpthread`. I assume that my implementation of the standard is doing the appropriate linking for me (or dynamically loading the appropriate libraries at runtime, I don't know nor should I care (in most cases)).

Comment: @MartinYork I'm asking about implementation details. This is not a "according to the standard ..." question, this is an "in practice ..." question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<thread> <mutex> <condition_variable> <future> <shared_mutex> <stop_token>` all use Pthreads types and functions.

The Networking TS  headers such as `<experimental/net>` and `<experimental/executor>` use `<mutex>` and `<future>` so they also depend on Pthreads.

We'll soon be adding more concurrency headers such as `<latch> <barrier> <semaphore>`.

Basically anything related to concurrency and synchronization, **except** `<atomic>` which notably does not depend on anything from Pthreads.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so much header files, but specific functionality.  Anything that creates threads under the hood will need or greatly benefit from linking with `-lpthread`, such as [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) from `<future>`.

Comment: gcc and clang require `-pthread` option when compiling and linking mulit-threaded apps. `-lpthread` is neither necessary nor sufficient.

Comment: `-pthread` has been equivalent to `-lpthread` for a decade or two on Linux. POSIX only specifies `-lpthread` (and not `-pthread`).

Comment: gcc and clang require `-pthread` and it is not equivalent to `-lpthread`. POSIX didn't produce a compiler.

Comment: Current POSIX specifies the `c99` command, which is a C compiler.

Comment: Try `c99 --version` on your system. IMO, that text about `-lpthread` in POSIX standard is actually incorrect and should be removed to not confuse people.

Answer (score 1):

On Solaris prior to version 10, `errno` was a global variable in a single-threaded build, but a macro expanding into a function call in a multi-threaded build. That was a source of problems when people linked multi-threaded apps with single-threaded libraries unwittingly. See [Compiling Multithreaded Code](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NF-C2ZQZXekC&lpg=PA152&ots=OblAuYd_MN&dq=solaris%20standard%20library%20single%20threaded%20errno&pg=PA151#v=onepage&q&f=false) for more details.

On Linux, `errno` is always a macro expanding into a function call that reads a thread-specific `errno` regardless whether `-pthread` is specified.

Compiling with `-pthread` defines macro `_REENTRANT`, but none of the GNU C and C++ standard library headers use that macro. Boost library does use it.